# Instantiate a class without knowing its type until runtime and without reflection

Tags: java

Is there any way to instantiate a class without knowing its type until runtime and without using reflection?

It would seem that if all the classes I wish to instantiate extend the same abstract class or implement the same interface, this is a reasonable request. However, because you cannot enforce a constructor on those classes even if they do, I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: **It is not possible** to instantiate an object of a class indirectly without using reflection.

Comment: The question would make more sense to me if it said "without knowing its type at compile time."  I doubt there is a way to instantiate a class without knowing its type at runtime.

Comment: @emory Yep, sorry. Changed "at runtime" to "until runtime".

Answer (score 1):

No. Part of the reason for creating reflection in the first place was to make it so you could do things like instantiate a class at runtime without knowing its type in advance.

You sound like you're asking how to something like this where $CLASS is the name of a package defined at runtime:

```
eval {
    require "$CLASS";
};
die $@ if $@;
$newObj = $CLASS->new();
```

Well, dude, that's why Sun added reflection...

Comment: I don't see why my performance should suffer by using reflection to instantiate the class when I know the class extends some known abstract class. It ain't right.

Comment: @Mark: What profiling have you done to show that reflection isn't performant enough in your application?

Comment: @RyanStewart none, but its always more efficient to instantiate the class directly. This is more of a theoretical question (although I have a use for it at the moment).

Comment: @Mark: As I've pointed out recently, it's also more efficient to program in assembly. Don't optimize without reason. Reflection is much faster than it used to be, and it's most likely used all over the place anyway if you're using any kind of framework.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you described is unresolvable, but you may be looking for something like [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A Java [service](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/extensible/) may provide what you are looking for.  (See [ServiceLoader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) javadoc too.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you know the names of the classes in advance, then you could use mock classes.

```
public class MySquareClass { public String methods ( ) { throw new RuntimeException ( ) ; }
public class MyCircleClass { ... stub methods ... }
...
```

You can use them in the code and the compiler will not know they are not "real implementations."  Be sure to substitute the real implementions by runtime.